# How to hold the console open in C?

Tags: c, console

What is a 'nice' standard way of holding the console open in C? I'm looking for something similar to `cin.clear(), cin.get();` in C++.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows, perhaps ?

Comment: When you say standard, do you mean portable?

Comment: The notion of a "console" is not in any way *standard* in either C or C++, so you're starting with a false premise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my program's output flash and close in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048975/why-does-my-programs-output-flash-and-close-in-windows)

Comment: @Paul R Oh, come one, do I really have to be so verbose in every single question I ask, even though my intent is clear? I obviously meant keeping the main function from returning and exiting until the user presses a key.

Comment: No verbosity issue here but lack of a good issue description and failure to google.

Comment: Your intent may be clear to *you*, but it's not at all obvious to me. "Holding the console open" is pretty vague. If you actually meant "keeping the main function from returning and exiting until the user presses a key" then you should probably have said that in your question.

Comment: No, it's really not obvious what "holding the console open" means.  The C++ fragment helps, but not enough; you might do that for any number of reasons other than what you said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
puts("Press <enter> to quit:");
getchar();
```

That's assuming you need to do this in the program, which is probably not a good idea in general.  And if I run your program from a shell, I'm going to be a bit annoyed at the extra step when I'm expecting the program to terminate nicely and let me have my next prompt.

Comment: Thanks. I only use this in programs I'm asked to do in class, not in real world programs.

Comment: Why isn't this method not working for me? (as of 2023)

Comment: @Scott I don't know. How exactly is it not working? What system are you running on? How are you running your program?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. But, `system("pause");` worked for me 

Comment: I have no idea why `getchar()` wouldn't work if `system("pause")` did. And without more information (how did it fail, how did you run the program), I never will.

Comment: doesnt work for me either, Win 10 x64 VS 17

Comment: @DrBwts Same question: How exactly did it not work?

Comment: @KeithThompson turns out it was a bug that shut the program down before it got to the pause, all works now, nothing to see here.....

Answer (score 1):

I use the below 2 lines of code.

```
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");
getchar();
```

Comment: That looks remarkably similar to [the answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813074/827263) 7 years before yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Windows only */
#include <stdlib.h>

system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
while (1) { sleep 3600; }
```

Or do you need to be able to respond to a keypress? If so, and you want to stick to the standard C library, then use scanf. Beware of buffer overruns.

What are you trying to do here? If you just need to keep your terminal open when your program exits, that's something you should set in your terminal emulator, not in your program.

Comment: Yup, a key press would be nice. Besides, is there even a standard sleep function to being with?

Comment: "that's something you should set in your terminal emulator, not in your program" -- This isn't for real-world programs. I'd only use it in small programs that I'm asked to do in class.

Comment: @Paul: No, there is no `sleep` function in standard C (there is one in POSIX).

Comment: You can usually find sleep in unistd.h on unix boxes. Windows also has a sleep that is roughly compatible, but it lives in Winbase.h.

Comment: I'd go with scanf() in that case.

Answer (score 0):

used to get a character from console but does not echo to the screen

getch();

Comment: `getch` is non-standard. For that matter, there are at least two very different functions by that name, one defined in the old Windows `<conio.h>` header, and one defined by curses / ncurses.