# How can I check my output without using Getch() in C

Tags: c, getch

I just want to see my output without using any function e.g. Getch ().

is it possible?

```
Void main()
{
printf(" hello ");

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hold the console open in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812968/how-to-hold-the-console-open-in-c)

Comment: @Ibrennan208 OP asks how to do it _without_ adding any function calls, so, no, it doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: Just start your program from a terminal, not via some "Run" button in an IDE.

Comment: You should not get used to that weird `void main()` signature. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` instead.

Comment: @Gerhardh: with that capital "V" in "Void", it will not even compile, do not worry.

Comment: @virolino that is obviously a typo. They will change to `void` and get used to that nasty habbit.

Answer (score 2):

### Alas, the answer is ***no***, not without adding functions.

But adding functions is the wrong way to do it anyway.

##### Windows Executable Subprocess Types

Every Windows executable (a [PE32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)) contains a flag that describes the [subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem) required to execute it. For most programs it will indicate either GUI or textual/console.
<sub>There are other subsystems, but I’ll pretend they don’t exist for this answer.</sub>

Most C (and C++) programs containing `main()` are textual, requiring a Windows Console (or Windows Terminal) to be attached to it when it is executed.

There are two<sup>[1]</sup> ways for this to happen:

1. You execute the program from an extant console/terminal window, to which the program’s standard I/O is automatically attached. Your program isn’t the only process using that console window, so when it terminates the window remains.
2. You execute the program from Explorer (or via some other process), so Windows *creates* a console/terminal window and attaches your program’s standard I/O to it. Your program is the only process attached to that console, so when it terminates Windows also closes the console window.

<sup>[1] There are more than two ways, but I’ll limit the discussion to those two.</sup>

##### Your IDE Is Acting Stupid

When you run it from the IDE you are getting option 2. The IDE ran your program, Windows helpfully created a console window for you, and when your program terminates Windows cleans up by removing the console window.

There are two ways to fix this without modifying your code:

1. Tell your IDE to keep the console window open until you press the (in)famous <kbd>Any</kbd> key. Many IDEs have this capability. You just need to find it in your IDE’s configuration/settings/whatever.
2. Run your program directly from a console window. To get a console window:

   1. Use Explorer to navigate to where your program’s (newly compiled) `.exe` is.
   2. Click on the Address/URI bar (the one showing the path to the folder you are viewing) and type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   3. A new Windows Console will appear!
   4. Type the name of your program. For example, if my program compiles to `example.exe` then I would type `example` (with or without the `.exe`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   5. Re-compile and re-use the console for as long as you need. When you are done, either click the big [ X ] button at the top of the console window or type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The console window will disappear.

That’s all there is to it!

<sub>Wow this is a boring-looking answer. Sorry about that.</sub>

Comment: BTW, this answer is for Windows only. Need an answer for Linux? Comment here to get one.

Answer (score -1):

In C you need to flush to the console in order to print.
You can do so by adding '\n' (newline) at the end of the string you're printing.
Also make sure to use proper indentation.
The following code should work:

```
Void main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

Comment: On Windows you do not need to flush. The need to flush depends entirely on the OS and/or terminal. It is a _good idea_ to always flush.

Comment: Additionally, even without the final `'\n'` the buffered output is flushed when the program quits. (Set aside abnormal exits ... of course)