# CreateProcess in C closes console too fast

Tags: c, multithreading

I am using [createProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) in C to open a command prompt to execute  a jar . I have figured out all the kinks but for sake of debugging would like to somehow add something where the console just does not flash and is gone immediately.

What I am looking is for the jar to be executed and command window wait for a button press from me before it terminates.

This will only be for debugging and I will remove it before putting it out so as the console window does not hang and kill everything down the line.

```
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "java -jar testfile.jar",        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        ){
            MessageBox(0, "test jar passed", "jar executed", 1);
            return 1;
        }
    else {
        printf("create process call to jar was sucessful");
        MessageBox(0,"jar failed", "Error Test", 1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am not using it IDE but installing on a different system so I need to create dll. Cant use IDE feature's to stall command prompt there

Comment: How do you open the command prompt exactly?

Comment: createProcess is clickable check it out

Comment: How do **YOU** use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my program's output flash and close in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048975/why-does-my-programs-output-flash-and-close-in-windows)

Comment: Try `java -jar testfile.jar & pause` instead of your command line..

Comment: @EugeneSh. did not work any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the blinking of console, you can use `getch()`.

`getch()` waits for user to input character. If you don't have `getch()`, you can use other functions like `getche()`,`getchar()`. But unlike `getch()` it takes an extra newline.

I think it solves your problem.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: `getch` is an MSVC function in `conio`. You can use the standard `getchar` - just hit `Enter` to complete the program execution. There is no *extra* `newline`.

Comment: @SkrewEverything it did not work just flashed and quit

Comment: @Praveen Where did you added `getch()`? In your code, is `return` meant for `main()`? If yes, you need to add `getch()` before your both the return statements.

Comment: @SkrewEverything I added it in else part before the message box. That is correct right ?

Comment: @Praveen You should also add it in `if` part before `return`.

Comment: @SkrewEverything it goes in else block cause the command prompt executes sucessfully the issue is that java version has  a mismatch. I verified it comes in else part

Comment: @Praveen Can you edit your question with your whole updated code. Along with `main()`.

Comment: it is actually part of dll and quite hairy inside. I will try few things and get back if something works

Comment: @Praveen I think you need to identify the line where the program gets terminated. Try to debug in the command line and write `getch()` before that line. Straight and simple.